# Observable property in css background-image path

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have simple polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  <polymer-element name="click-counter">
    <template>
      <style>
        div {
          font-size: {{size}}pt;
        }
        #btn {
          background-image: url({{img}});
        }
     </style>
   <div style="" id="btn">div</div>
 </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>
```

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @observable int size = 24;
  @observable String img = "some_img.png";

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {}
}
```

It works well with polymer 0.9.5 package, but after upgrade to 0.11.0+5 the url for `background-image` is set incorrectly to `%7B%7Bimg%7D%7D`. The second observable `size` still has right value in template. 
It is also worth to mention that the problem doesn't exist when I put `background-image` property in inline style. Is it bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960402/polymer-image-as-background-with-data-binding/24963208#24963208
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/270

Comment: There is an open issue for that https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17075